# Error refreshing state: HTTP remote state endpoint requires auth while running terraform init

Tags: terraform, gitlab, yaml, cicd

I am trying to deploy VPC into AWS account with GitLab pipelines using terraform. However, I am getting "HTTP remote state endpoint requires auth" error.

In GitLab environment I have a project with below files:

```
main.tf
# Creating VPC in AWS
resource "aws_vpc" "GitLabCICDprovidedVPCtest" {
  cidr_block       = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  instance_tenancy = "default"

  tags = {
    Name = "Demo-VPC"
  }
}
```

```
provider.tf
# Configure provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }
  # Configure correct authentication details for the GitLab remote state backend
  backend "http" {
    address        = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxx1/terraform/state/xxxprivate"
    lock_address   = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxx1/terraform/state/xxxprivate"
    unlock_address = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxx1/terraform/state/xxxprivate"
    username       = "gitlab-ci-token"
    password       = "xxxx" #token
  }
}

# Configure and downloading plugins for aws
provider "aws" {
  region = var.aws_region
}
```

```
variables.tf
# Defining Region
variable "aws_region" {
  default = "eu-west-1"
}

# Defining CIDR Block for VPC
variable "vpc_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

```
.gitlab-ci.yml
# Image/GitLab runner provided by xxx (GitLab runner process only tasks that use tags)
image:
  name: registry.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx/xxx-packer:latest

# Stages to process by Terraform
stages:
 - validate
 - plan
 - apply

# Script will be process in CLI of the GitLab runner before Terraform stages
before_script:
# export variables which were configured in CICD GitLab
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
  - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
# instalation of terraform on docker ubuntu linux
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg software-properties-common
  - wget -O- https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg
  - gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg --fingerprint
  - echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com $(lsb_release -cs) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list
  - apt update
  - apt-get install terraform=1.1.7
# moving into terraform directory
  - cd /builds/personalawsaccount/aws_cicd_test_private/terraform
# Performing terraform init to create state file
  - terraform init 

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - cd /builds/personalawsaccount/aws_cicd_test_private/terraform
    - terraform validate
  tags:
    - docker

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - cd /builds/personalawsaccount/aws_cicd_test_private/terraform
    - terraform plan
  tags:
    - docker
  dependencies:
    - validate
    
apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - cd /builds/personalawsaccount/aws_cicd_test_private/terraform
    - terraform apply
  tags:
    - docker
  dependencies:
    - plan
```

However, wehen I check the pipeline I can see:

```
$ apt-get install terraform=1.1.7
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  terraform
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 63.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com bionic/main amd64 terraform amd64 1.1.7 [18.8 MB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 18.8 MB in 2s (11.0 MB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package terraform.
(Reading database ... 7791 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../terraform_1.1.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking terraform (1.1.7) ...
Setting up terraform (1.1.7) ...
$ cd /builds/personalawsaccount/aws_cicd_test_private/terraform
$ terraform init
Initializing the backend...
Successfully configured the backend "http"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Error refreshing state: HTTP remote state endpoint requires auth
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I can not understand why I am getting "HTTP remote state endpoint requires auth" and how to fix it.

My variables:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8e5p.png)

- I have changed

```
username = "gitlab-ci-token"
```

to

```
username = "myAccountName"
```

I have also followed multiple blogs to modify *.gitlab-ci.yml* and *provider.tf* and read few Stack Overflow topics but everything lead still to the same result "HTTP remote state endpoint requires auth"

I am expecting to run pipeline and execute successfully terraform init/validate/plan/apply to deploy vpc into my aws account.